# Converting one column to multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

At first sight I thought it would be a piece of cake to write a parse to do the job.

But then I got myself in a deep rabbit hole, which seems impossible to get out, investigation what would be the best technique to manipulate strings, sets and lists in python.

Is converting one column to multiple columns of a dataframe in Pandas so difficult?

Source's a CSV file within 3 columns, as in:
file,coords,areas
0001.png,['181.5;339.5', '236.54166666666666;201.583333...],[136.0, 153.0, 44.5, 43.0, 57.5, 68.0, 153.0, ...

After importing CSV file was into a pandas dataframe. The second and third columns were assigned as type of Series

```
print('type:', type(df1.x_y_coords))
print('type:', type(df1.area))

type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

[image]

Columns coords and areas must be split to multiple columns, where each element of the Series (i.e. python list) must become a column of the dataframe

as in the static example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file','coords','areas'])
```

...
(column's transformation)
...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file','c1','c2','c3','c4',...,'a1','a2','a3','a4',...])
```

Another challenge's the fact that columns will vary depending on the length of original columns: coords and areas. Meaning, file can have 8 coords and 8 areas, and another file might have 14 coords and 14 areas.

So that empty columns can be populated with null.

Coords and areas have always the same length. In fact, they are the coordinates and area of a figure in a plan.

What would be the best technique to convert such columns to multiple columns of a dataframe in Pandas?

Comment: It would help, if you would create full sample/mock input data and show expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want by doing `merge` + `apply(pd.Series)`

```
df.merge(df.x_y_coords.apply(pd.Series),
         left_index=True, 
         right_index=True)
```

However, it seems like you need to parse this before loading to a DataFrame.

---

Sample data used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'frame': ['0001.png', '0002.png'],
              'x_y_coords': [ ['1.0', '2.0', '3.0'],
                              ['4.0', '5.0']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
def h_explode(df, cols):
    for col in cols:
        df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop(col).tolist())
                               .rename(lambda x: f"{col[0]}{x+1}", axis=1))
    return df

out = df.pipe(h_explode, ["coords", "areas"])
```

Output :

```
print(out)

       file                   c1          c2          c3     a1     a2     a3
0  0001.png          181.5;339.5  236.541666  201.583333  136.0  153.0   44.5
1  0002.png  232.22727;47.818183        None        None   54.5   73.0  160.5
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "file": ["0001.png", "0002.png"],
    "coords": [["181.5;339.5", "236.541666", "201.583333"], ["232.22727;47.818183"]],
    "areas": [[136.0, 153.0, 44.5], [54.5, 73.0, 160.5]]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "file": "0001.png",
    "coords": [["181.5;339.5", "236.54166666666666", "201.583333"]],
    "areas": [[136.0, 153.0, 44.5]]}
)
df[[f'a{i}' for i, _ in enumerate(df['areas'].iloc[0])]] = pd.DataFrame(df['areas'].to_list(), index=df.index)
df[[f'c{i}' for i, _ in enumerate(df['coords'].iloc[0])]] = pd.DataFrame(df['coords'].to_list(), index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely `Series.str.split()` seems the way to go!

I tried the following command line:

```py
df_coords = df1['x_y_coords'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'','').replace(' ', '').split(',')))
df_coords
```

which returned the following dataframe:

[image]

and now, it's just a matter of cleaning up and renaming and merging.

I found good resources info in the documentation bellow:

[https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-split-column/#:~:text=In%20Pandas%2C%20the%20apply(),to%20split%20into%20two%20columns](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-split-column/#:%7E:text=In%20Pandas%2C%20the%20apply(),to%20split%20into%20two%20columns).

Thanks for the quick feedback! As usual! ;)
Best wishes,